# Equal of pcre regex in posix regex c++

Tags: php, c++, regex

Hello this is my string

```
Data1 = "value1";
Data2 = "value2";
Data3 = "value3";
```

in php i am using this regex

```
preg_match("/\h*(.*?)\h*[=]\h*[\"](.*?)[\"]\h*[;]/mis", $input_line, $output_array);
```

and get 3 result

```
Data1 = "value1";
Data1
Value1
...
...
```

now i want to use regex in c++ visual studio to do like this (what i done in php). i know we can't find

```
\h*
```

in c++ regex so please say to me what regex i must use for c++?

Comment: I don't know `c++` but you could try the plain space character with the `*`, or for tabs too possible `[ \t]*`. See https://regex101.com/r/zI8vS3/2 and https://regex101.com/r/zI8vS3/1

Comment: `[[:blank:]]*` should be what you are looking for. You can also add your own [shorthands](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_traits/lookup_classname) with `regex_traits` if you want to define `\h` yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\h` matches horizontal whitespace.
It includes tabulations and unicode spaces. It's the same as `[\t\p{Zs}]`

If you don't want to match all unicode spaces, you can simply use `[\t ]` that matches tabulations and simple spaces.